# Reactjs change state on nested function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to run a method from a child component that changes the parent's state, however, it gives me a maximum update depth exceeded error. here is my render method:

````
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.options.map(option => (
          <Permitoption
            onClick={this.handleClick(option.id)}
          >
          </Permitoption>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
how can I access the state?
````

Comment: You are calling the function `this.handleClick` instead of assigning to `onClick`.

Comment: add more code or elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, when you use `()`, you are calling the function instead of assigning it.

You could assign the ID to your component and use it in your function call, something similar to this:

```
<Permitoption id={option.id} onClick={this.handleClick} >
```

And you `handleClick` would be:

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    const id = event.currentTartget.id;
}
```

*Just wrote it from the top of my head, but I think you can go from here...*

Comment: did not fix it, I still have the maximum update depth exceeded error

Comment: Hmm, so could you update your answer and post more of your code? Maybe there is something else...